# Java file copy to non empty destination folder

Tags: java, file, path, move

I'm having real difficulties figuring out how this needs to be coded without using FileUtils import. I have found thousands of tutorials on how to move files to empty folders, that's easy. The difficulty is finding out how Java can move files to directories that already have files in the folder. As I understand it the REPLACE_EXISTING parameter means it will overwrite identical file names if detected in the destination directory, but the directory doesn't have a file with a matching name of the file I'm attempting to copy/move. What am I missing? How can I make this happen?

java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException occuring.

```
enter code here

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;



public class Move {
 static File source = new File("sourcefolderhere");
static File destination = new File("destfolderhere");


public static void move(File src, File dest) throws IOException {
    Files.move(src.toPath().toAbsolutePath(), dest.toPath().toAbsolutePath(),
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);         
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

try {       
    if(source.isDirectory() && destination.isDirectory()) {         
        File[] content = source.listFiles();           
        for(int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(content[i]);  
            move(source, destination);                
        }            
    }
    else if (!destination.isDirectory()){ 
        System.out.println("create folder here");
        destination.mkdir();
        File[] content = source.listFiles();           
        for(int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            move(source, destination);              
        }
    }
 }
 catch(Exception ex) {   System.out.println(ex);    
 }
 finally {
    
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: If you *know* that the destination directory doesn't have any files with matching names to the source files you're copying/moving, then there is no conflict, and the destination directory might as well be considered empty. I don't understand what your perceived problem is. What are you really trying to ask here?

Comment: If the directory already has a file with the same name how are you going to put another file with the same name there one more time?
I would suggest you to add another IF branch with a check: if there is a file with such name - you change name of a new one to some other value. if not -> you copy file normally.

Comment: Tell if I understood your intention correctly and I will provide you a piece of code that adds indices suffix in a cycle until file name is unique.

Comment: Please try this snipet. It is without FileUtils                                                         `private static void copy(File src, File dest) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(src); OutputStream os new FileOutputStream(dest) {
            // buffer size 1K
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
                os.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } 
    }`

Comment: REPLACE_EXISTING does not *require* an existing file with the same name to exist.  Use of REPLACE_EXISTING means that *if a file with the same name exists,* it should be overwritten.  If there is no existing file with the same name, REPLACE_EXISTING is ignored.

Comment: What I'm asking is how can I move files into a folder that already has files in it. I get java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException. I need to be able to move files into a folder with content not just move to empty directories.

Comment: If you’re getting an exception, that is crucial information.  Please edit your question, and include the *entire stack trace* of that exception in your question.  Also, since we can’t see your program’s line numbers, please tell us which line of your code triggered the exception according to the stack trace.  (My guess is that you’re trying to move a non-empty directory using `Files.move`.)

Comment: Line numbers aren't necessary, all of the code is there minus source and destination locations. It's designed to create a destination folder if there isn't one, but once there is a destination folder and files are in it, it needs to continue putting more files into the destination as they arrive in the source. So yes, I am moving the contents of the source to the contents of the destination. That's why I titled the subject of my post 'copy to non empty destination folder'. If I resolve this, the directorynotemptyexception takes care of itself, that's why I didn't waste time mentioning it.

Comment: *"how can I move files into a folder that already has files in it"* --- By moving the **files**, not the *directory*. `DirectoryNotEmptyException` indicates that you're trying the move the directory itself, not the individual files within the directory.

Comment: Look at your code inside the `if(source.isDirectory() ...` block. You call `move(source, destination);` for each iteration of the loop, but neither `source` nor `destination` is changed by the loop. How can that be correct? Answer: It isn't. Check your logic!!

Comment: Once the destination folder has been created, on every subsequent run, when would `if(source.isDirectory() && destination.isDirectory())` ever be false? You have repetitive code. Re-think your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code in IDE File.move method with parameter StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING works only if you have file in the destination folder. otherwise use File.move the normal way. I have also modified your code a little just to avoid code duplication.

````
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Move {
    static File source = new File("sourcefolderhere");
    static File destination = new File("destfolderhere");

    public static void move(File src, File dest) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(src.getName());
        if(isExist(src.getName()))
            Files.move(src.toPath().toAbsolutePath(), Paths.get(destination.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+src.getName()) , StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        else
            Files.move(src.toPath().toAbsolutePath(), Paths.get(destination.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+src.getName()));
    }
    
    public static boolean isExist(String souceFileName){
        //If you are not using java 8 code
        /*String[] destFiles = destination.list();
        for(String fileName : destFiles){
            if(souceFileName.equals(fileName))
                return true;
        }
        return false;*/
        return Arrays.stream(destination.list())
                .anyMatch(fileName -> fileName.equals(souceFileName));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {
            if(!source.isDirectory())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Source Folder doesn't Exist");
            if(!destination.exists())
                destination.mkdir();
            if (source.isDirectory() && destination.isDirectory()) {
                File[] content = source.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(content[i]);
                    move(content[i], destination);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } finally {

        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, it still doesn't copy a file to directory that already has content. I still get file.DirectoryNotEmptyException

Comment: I tried with the following scenario. destfldr -> file1.txt sourcefldr -> file1.txt,file2.txt. The result was destfldr -> file1.txt,file2.txt and sourcefldr -> *nofile*. It works for me! Is the file move recursive? mean does it have nested folder to move?

Comment: That's just it, I'm not entering file names manually, I'm iterating through the folder for each file. The names change and I have no way of knowing what the new names will be.

Comment: Can you give me an example with files and folders of source and destination

Comment: I don't use individual files.  static File source = new File("\\\\server\folder\folder");